# How to use OpenSearch?

Tags: smartsearch

Forgive my ignorance about OpenSearch, but after providing the OpenSearch name and description, I have no idea how to see if it's in effect, or where to see evidence that the site is "openly" searchable.

Can someone explain briefly what the expected results are of configuring the OpenSearch information?

Comment: Are you sure this is related to Joomla?

Comment: Yes, from the Admin, It's the last two fields of the Smart Search Options